# Strange failure from some Internet connections for rdap responses using httpClient, but never through postman

Tags: .net, f#, postman, rdap

I'm trying to write an app that will allow any user located anywhere in the world to get an rdap response for the corresponding tld for any domain name, based upon the official rdap server list here: https://data.iana.org/rdap/dns.json, whilst using their own local internet connection.

Something strange is happening however. When using my local Internet connection (based in southeast asia at the moment), the following query for google.com (at the corresponding rdap server for .com, which is https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/) will fail around 80% of the time:

```
open System.Net.Http

let httpClient = new HttpClient()
let resp = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com").Result
resp
```

Here's the error received:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at FSI_0138.makeRequestWithHeaders(String url)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0138>.$FSI_0138.main@()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at FSI_0138.makeRequestWithHeaders(String url)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0138>.$FSI_0138.main@()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

Nothing really interesting about that, could easily be explained away by some local ISP issues, right?

However, the request works 100% of the time in postman. Eg:
[image]

This *never* fails. Interesting!

So I thought of capturing packets in Wireshark. The below shows the communication from F# using httpClient (my real IP has been replaced with "myip"):

```
95  2.307971    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TCP 86  4   63296 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64952 Len=0 MSS=1412 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
106 2.550129    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  myip    TCP 78  4   443 → 63296 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=1240 Len=0 MSS=1240
107 2.550336    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TCP 74  4   63296 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64952 Len=0
108 2.550804    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TLSv1.2  253 4   Client Hello
118 3.112553    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TCP 253 4   [TCP Retransmission] 63296 → 443 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64952 Len=179
134 3.832227    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TCP 253 4   [TCP Retransmission] 63296 → 443 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64952 Len=179
159 5.264697    myip    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  TCP 253 4   [TCP Retransmission] 63296 → 443 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64952 Len=179
215 7.797828    rdap-1.verisigndns.com  myip    TCP 74  4   443 → 63296 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=24000 Len=0
```

As can be seen, the rdap server seems to be ignoring my client requests after the successful handshake.

Here is the network traffic within postman, which works:

```
19193  526.178083  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  66  98  53194 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
19199  526.406075  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TCP  58  98  443 → 53194 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=1480 Len=0 MSS=1412
19200  526.406368  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  53194 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
19201  526.407322  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TLSv1.3  571  98  Client Hello
19208  526.638776  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TLSv1.3  1454  98  Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
19209  526.639594  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TCP  1454  98  443 → 53194 [ACK] Seq=1401 Ack=518 Win=28944 Len=1400 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
19210  526.639648  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  53194 → 443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=2801 Win=64952 Len=0
19211  526.640264  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TLSv1.3  1003  98  Application Data, Application Data, Application Data
19212  526.641121  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TLSv1.3  368  98  Change Cipher Spec, Application Data, Application Data
19213  526.645057  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TCP  54  98  443 → 53194 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=28944 Len=0
19214  526.645082  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  [TCP Dup ACK 19212#1] 53194 → 443 [ACK] Seq=832 Ack=3750 Win=64003 Len=0
19219  526.868863  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TLSv1.3  293  98  Application Data
19220  526.870003  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TLSv1.3  1454  98  Application Data
19221  526.870305  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  53194 → 443 [ACK] Seq=832 Ack=5389 Win=64952 Len=0
19222  526.870775  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TCP  1454  98  443 → 53194 [ACK] Seq=5389 Ack=832 Win=30016 Len=1400 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
19223  526.871672  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TLSv1.3  127  98  Application Data
19224  526.871895  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  53194 → 443 [ACK] Seq=832 Ack=6863 Win=64952 Len=0
19225  526.878734  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  54  98  [TCP Previous segment not captured] 53194 → 443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=856 Ack=6863 Win=64952 Len=0
19226  526.878795  myip  rdap.verisign.com  TCP  78  98  [TCP Out-Of-Order] 53194 → 443 [PSH, ACK] Seq=832 Ack=6863 Win=64952 Len=24
19231  527.125064  rdap.verisign.com  myip  TCP  60  98  [TCP Dup ACK 19219#1] 443 → 53194 [ACK] Seq=6863 Ack=832 Win=300
```

So I thought perhaps for some reason the rdap server is rejecting traffic from the .NET httpClient, but not postman (although this of course wouldn't make sense since the rdap service should be expecting a majority of its requests to come from an automated source, and not manual requests from postman). I tried manually setting then the headers to replicate postman in .NET:

```
open System.Net.Http
open System.Net.Http.Headers

let makeRequestWithHeaders (url: string) =
    let httpClient = new HttpClient()
    // Add headers similar to what Postman sends
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("PostmanRuntime/7.26.10")
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json")
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl <- CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache")

    let response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result
    response

let url = "https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com"
let resp = makeRequestWithHeaders url
resp
```

However nothing changed (still only a ~20% success rate).

Now here is where things become very strange. I connected to a US VPN server (via NordVPN), and now the .NET code works 100% of the time without any failures (and of course, postman still works too).

But, if I connect to some regional VPN servers, similar issues are encountered but for *different* RDAP servers! For instance, if connecting to the Argentina VPN via NordVPN, then  https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com works just fine, however the official rdap server for .limo for example, fails (https://rdap.identitydigital.services/rdap/). Below is an example of the failing .NET code:

```
open System.Net.Http

let httpClient = new HttpClient()
let resp = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://rdap.identitydigital.services/rdap/domain/virginia.limo/").Result
resp
```

(fails *only* on the Argentina nord VPN server, not from any other server, or from my local internet connection).

So I've made the following observations regarding RDAP official servers:

1. My local Internet connection can query .limo domains fine within both .NET and Postman, but only .com domains from within postman (and not .NET)
2. The NordVPN Argentina server can query .com domains fine within both .NET and Postman, but only .limo domains from within postman (and not .NET)
3. The NordVPN US server can query all extensions/domains fine without ever encountering a failure, both within .NET and postman.

This perplexing series of facts rules out a lot of plausible causes such as issues with httpClient, SSL protocol, etc, because if it was any of those things, then surely it should always fail, and switching to a different IP and geolocation shouldn't solve it?

So are some RDAP servers for some reason denying requests from certain geolocations some of the time if they come from httpClient, but never if they come from postman? And why is it not the same RDAP servers, eg: the official .com server accepts Argentina traffic fine, but denies my local IP sometimes, whilst the official .limo rdap server accepts my local traffic fine, but denies Argentina traffic sometimes.

It's very perplexing, and I'm after any feedback as to what may be the issue here? If this is truly a fault of the different RDAP servers and some weird policies they have, then I can chalk it up to being outside my control, but I'd like to make sure that's really the case before drawing that conclusion.

Caveats:

1. This has nothing to do with calling .Result on GetAsync, which works fine for illustration purposes
2. Both my local connection and the Argentina nordVPN server can query websites directly just fine (both from .NET and postman), the issue is only encountered when interacting with the official rdap servers.

***Update (19th November 2023) - 2 days later***

My local Internet connection today is working fine for all requests, just as if it were connected to the NordVPN US VPN, however the Argentina VPN is still failing on .limo

This is more and more looking like 3rd party networking issues but where, how or why I don't understand

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could it have anything to do with DNS and the PooledConnectionLifetime setting for the HttpClient client?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#dns-behavior

Comment: @CoopC Thanks for the suggestion I looked into this. From what I can deduce this is rather if the httpClient instance will persist for the lifetime of the application? But for the code snippets in my question the program is re-executed each time they're run. I was wondering then if some TCP connections may be left open causing the issue once the program is finished executing, but the fact everything works fine from the NordVPN US server makes me think this is unlikely.

Comment: Just a guess but could it be related to using .Result on the task?  That can block the thread.  Maybe use |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously instead?

Comment: @Foole I don't think so since the surrounding code is all synchronous